# TextFeild Widget in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, widget

How can i reduce the height of the textfeild by using the property of the textfeild widget

I want to increase and decrease the hight of the textfeild by using the textfeild widget property.

I tried wrapping the textfeild widget with sizebox and container but when a validation error occurs, the height of the textfeild is broken.
So now give a solusion that can maintain the height of the textfeild by using the property of the textfeild widget.
And even if a validation error comes from that solusion, its height will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the contentPadding like below

for example:

```
 decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 12, horizontal:16),
      ),
```

Comment: In this solution, when an error occurs, the error text, the label text and the end controller's text are joint.

Comment: If you still using the **SizedBox** please do not use it. Do not give height for the TextField.

Comment: So what should I do to make the height & width smaller